# htaccess rewrite to new domain and url starting and ending with

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My site's server is in the U.S. but I want to load images (and maybe later js and css) from a server in the visitors' country itself. I'm wondering what's a good way of rewriting only the images' urls that are in a specific directory.

Current url

```
http://www.myusserver.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg
```

url I want to use

```
http://www.myvisitorsserver.com/wp-content/uploads/image-name.jpg
```

I found this rewrite rule that does the job

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.myvisitorsserver.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

but I want to limit it to only images that are in the /wp-content/uploads directory.
I changed the rewrite to this

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/ http://www.myvisitorsserver.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

I think it's working, but I'm wondering if it's possible to rewrite only image urls. So, basically what I need is is to know how to rewrite and url starting with /wp-content/uploads and ending with an image extension.
I like this rule

```
RewriteRule ([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.myvisitorsserver.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

but I don't know how to change the first part of it to match /wp-content/uploads

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: _“I think it's working”_ - don’t see how; you are not _capturing_ anything in your regex, yet you are trying to use `$1` in the substitution - where should the latter come from?

Comment: The uploads folder usually has sub-folders - do you want those to be used in the substitution URL as well, or you you want to discard them and only use the image file name in the new URL?

Comment: No just the uploads folder. I don't use the contents in the sub-folders. I want to rewrite to the url structure as I mentioned in the 2nd example

Comment: Well then just prefixing your rule pattern with the static path should work, `RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ …`

Comment: "don’t see how; you are not capturing anything in your regex". I think it was working because I enabled the cdn function in litespeed cache... very smart of me

Comment: "Well then just prefixing your rule pattern with the static path should work". Yes this works indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to rewrite to the url structure as I mentioned in the 2nd example

Then just prefixing your rule pattern with the static path should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ http://www.myvisitorsserver.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```